# sql to replace two strings in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to replace two characters in a single string.

Replace

```
Name 
I am not aware of any or potential that hasn’t yet been reported
```

with

```
Name 
I am not aware of any/potential that hasn't yet been reported
```

I've used this query:

```
replace(Replace(Name, ' or ', '/'), '’', ''')
```

But I get an error

> ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Comment: tried using ''’'' but did not work

Comment: this is an apostrophe not a single quote. And i tried adding quotes around it one more but didnt work

Comment: It isn't complaining about the "smart" quote, it's failing because of the imbalanced single quote `'` on the end. Fix that and it works correctly `replace(Replace(Name,' or ','/'),'’','''')` . https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fe2e8a5b108cb893f15b0dd2c6af8263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you ary trying to do with your double replace. You can just use one:

```
SELECT REPLACE(name,' or ','/') newstring FROM yourstrings;
```

If you really need a double replace, you can do this, too:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(name,' or ','/'),'’','''') newstring FROM yourstrings;
```

More interesting is how to insert such strings which contain apostrophes, quotes etc. You can do it using the q operator, as example:

```
INSERT INTO yourstrings VALUES 
(q'[I am not aware of any or potential that hasn’t yet been reported ]');
```

Please see this working example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2d3a41455eea86e3376414786edd0eb)

Comment: In the first statment you are just replacing "or". I want to replace both or and "'"

Comment: If you see the first row there is "hasn’t" aporstrophe not single quotes

Comment: @JonasMetzler - If you look closer, it's not a single quote .. it's some sort of "smart" quote:  `hasn’t` not `hasn't`.  Though this same question has already been asked and answered *many* times ....

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. In the question you said you want to replace two characters, but you wanted to replace 3 ("or" are already 2) ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(replace
('I am not aware of any or potential that hasn’t yet been reported',' or ','/'),
'’','''') 
from dual;
```

Refer solution [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ae12141ffd7581e1a6710c4c2f5d48e)